# Adding system(cls); to program increases startup time

Tags: c

When I started writing my program (I didn't add system(cls); at that time), it started the console as soon as I doubled clicked on the exe file. But when I added the system(cls); it took 4-5 seconds to open. Why? Is there any way to fix this?

My Code (it's a simple calculator) -

```
#include <stdio.h> // for printf() and scanf()
#include <stdlib.h> //for exit() and system()
#include <windows.h> // for SetConsoleTitle()
#include <math.h> // for sqrt()
int calculation();

int main()
{
int afterCal;
SetConsoleTitle("My Calculator");
printf("Welcome to my Calculator\n");
calculation();
for(;;) 
{ 
    printf("\nAnother Calculation? type 1\n");
    printf("Quit? type 0\n");
    scanf( "%d", &afterCal); 
    if (afterCal == 1) 
    {
        system("cls");
        calculation();
    }
    else if (afterCal == 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else 
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\nError, enter 0 or 1\n");
    }   
}  
return 0;
}

int calculation()
{
double num1, num2;
char ope, square = 251;
printf("Enter number 1 -\n");
scanf("%lf", &num1);
printf("Enter number 2 (put 0 if you want square/cube root or cube) -\n");
scanf("%lf", &num2);
if (num2 == 0) 
{
    printf("Enter operation - s for square root, r for cube root, c for cube\n");
}
else 
{
    printf("Enter operation - +, -, *, /\n");
}
scanf(" %c", &ope);
switch (ope)
{
case '+':
    system("cls");
    printf("%g + %g = %g\n", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
    break;

case '-':
    system("cls");
    printf("%g - %g = %g\n", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
    break;

case '*':
    system("cls");
    printf("%g * %g = %g\n", num1, num2, num1 * num2);
    break;

case '/':
    system("cls");
    printf("%g / %g = %g\n", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
    break;

case 's':
    system("cls");
    printf("%c%g = %g\n", square, num1, sqrt(num1));
    break;

case 'r':
    system("cls");
    printf("Cube root of %g = %g\n", num1, cbrtf(num1));
    break;

case 'c':
    system("cls");
    printf("Cube of %g = %g\n", num1, num1 * num1 * num1);
    break;

default:
    system("cls");
    printf("Error, invalid operation %c\n", ope);
    break;
}
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it clear the console at all? Anyway, the `system()` call does a lot of work underneath, and its runtime depends heavily on your system.

Comment: `system("cls")` starts a new `CMD` process which executes the `cls` command. This may take some time, but normally not 4 seconds. There are other methods to clear the screen on a Windows system, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen that don't use an external program. Without seeing your source code it is difficult to give specific advice.

Comment: Hey Support Ukraine, I tried a separate program as you told me, and it worked surprisingly well. It opened instantly even though there was a system("cls"); in the program. I am uploading my main code which is taking 4 seconds to open.

Comment: Hey, the busybee, yes, system("cls"); clears the whole console.

Comment: Bodo, I am not that experienced programmer, I only want a 1 or 2 line command to clear the console like the system(cls). And that whole Microsoft page went over my brain.

Comment: The simplest thing is to forget clearing the screen. Just don't do it. You won't be missing anything. If your program is line-oriented, screen clearing is simply not needed. In addition, `cls` only works in a Windows console, not in various third party shells that run on that OS and not on other OSes.

Comment: It takes some kind of malware to burn 12 billion cpu cycles on clearing the screen.  Finding it is something you'll have to do yourself, start by disabling the installed anti-malware product.

Answer (score 0):

1st I was using the MinGW x64 compiler (at that time the startup delay occurred), but now I am using Visual Studio 2022 ide and its compiler, and my exe opens instantly! Problem Solved!

But I am still confused, why did MinGW give that much startup delay...